# Python Machine Learning to analyse test-case lab data and identify new test cases from real-world random data

Tags: machine-learning, python, bigdata

I am currently working on a project where I have predefined test-cases I need to run/test and then analyse the data. My aim is to be able to identify system failures (against pre-defined criteria). Eventually I would like to be able to present statistics of the failures vs test conditions and ideally get to the point where I can anticipate failure modes, even before these happen.

I have quasi-infinite amounts of random data generated by systems identical to the one under test, but being used in a random manner "in the real world" (i.e. not staged scenarios). From this random data I would like to be able to identify scenarios which are similar to the staged ones as well as new ones which have not yet been identified as use-cases.

The system under test is a control system. The ultimate goal is to verify that the control system behaves and reacts as expected/specified when subject to various conditions. In general I am dealing with flags and sequences thereof. (ex: temperature goes up,  electric motor gets derated. Load increases, current to motor increases to maintain speed.)

In essence therefore I am talking about 4 tasks within the same project:

1. Identify failing scenarios (Pass/Fail identification for the test cases is already being taken care of by other means, more or less)
2. Identify trends/patterns in causes of failure, therefore anticipate failure modes (ex: the motor is more likely to fail under hot conditions, and the failures are more likely to happen during transient modes.)
3. Identify Use cases from the real world which match the test-case scenario and therefore identify frequency of occurrence of each test-case scenario
4. Identify common use-cases from real world to create new test cases which may not have been thought of

I'm guessing this would qualify as machine learning(?)

I would mostly want to use Python for this as:

1. I am keen to become more proficient with the language (my experience so far has been limited to following tutorials).
2. It is pretty much the only thing I have at my disposal.

So, my main question at this point is (assuming this is even realistically possible, and I am going down the right path):

Are there any existing examples of something similar which I can look at?

Comment: Hi and welcome. A few suggestions: "Where do I start?" is not a good question title. Nobody will know what this question is about. "What is possible" and "Where do I start" are too broad questions for this type of forum. I feel there is a valid question in there where you describe your test-case problems. Please elaborate on the type of data you have and what exactly you are trying to accomplish as well as the current state of your work.

Comment: Hello and thanks for taking your time to read my question and make suggestions. I've edited my post to clarify my point. I hope this makes it better but please let me know if it doesn't and I'll try clarifying it further.

Comment: @Davysseus Please show some data.  e.g.  Input data, expected output.  This helps form the picture of what is and what needs to be.